Question for integrating Snowflake and Java using SnowflakeCatalog in Apahce Iceberg
In Iceberg, there is a SnowflakeCatalog which seems to facilitate integration with Snowflake. I want to utilize this to perform the following tasks:
Write data using pure Java with Iceberg's SnowflakeCatalog and make it accessible in Snowflake as shared data.
Conversely, read data written in Snowflake from pure Java through Iceberg.
I assume the above process is possible using SnowflakeCatalog. However, while trying to implement this with Java, I am encountering issues with connectivity or integration. It feels like the SnowflakeCatalog implementation in Iceberg's open source project is not fully developed, as the documentation is sparse, and the integration doesn't seem to work as expected.
Could you provide assistance with this, particularly on how to make SnowflakeCatalog work in Java for such use cases?
